# Python : audio is not coming after hosting

Tags: python, asp.net, python-3.x

I am executing a python script from .net to use gtts library  and pygame to execute audio output. its works fine on local but after hosting the python script is executing successfully  but audio is not coming

Given all the permission and added mime type for .mp3 also but didn't work

python code >

```py
import time
import sys

from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO
from pygame import mixer
from datetime import datetime


def speak():
    mp3_fp = BytesIO()
    tts = gTTS(sys.argv[2], lang=sys.argv[1])
    tts.write_to_fp(mp3_fp)
    return mp3_fp

mixer.init()
sound = speak()
sound.seek(0)
mixer.music.load(sound, "mp3")
mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(50)
```

.net code >

```
   string arg = string.Format(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Gtts/tts2.py {0} {1}"), "\"" + selectedlang + "\"", text);
        try
        {

            //p1.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\userss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe", arg);
            p1.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Python/Python311/python.exe"), arg);
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p1.Start();
            string output = p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            //string replacement = Regex.Replace(output, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
            // s = replacement.Substring(replacement.LastIndexOf("Gtts"));
            //myaudio.Src = "ipaddress/"+s+"";
         
            if (!p1.WaitForExit(100))
            {
                if (!p1.HasExited) p1.Kill();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is a problem in your Python code: " + ex.Message);
            lblmsg.Text = ex.StackTrace;
        }
```

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: added code in the question

Comment: You need to know the system boundaries very well before digging further into such questions. The Python script ended up running on the server side, not browser side, so the sound can only be heard on the server (in session 0 and usually without a sound card). You feel that it works locally simply because your local environment is completely different, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3